# Best practices for file storage in on-prem Kubernetes

Tags: java, pdf, nosql, kubernetes

I have a project that runs on Kubernentes and uses a microservices architecture.

The application will need to create and serve PDF files in two of its APIs.

I wonder what is the best practice to store such data in an on-premises Kubernetes cluster. S3 would have been a perfect fit but that is not possible since i'm not running on AWS.

I guess K8S persistent volume is an option, but I worry about handling data corruptuon and how to handlescaling. The number of PDFs can reach the hundreds of millions.

Would you consider a NoSQL solution as a viable alternative? Any specific implementation that would provide benefits compared to others?

Thanks.

Comment: Best practice questions typically get shutdown here. S3 is certainly possible you can use it just as you can from your local computer. You can also look into mounting NFS PVs

Comment: you might want to look into things like: Ceph, GlusterFS, Rook, Swift & Swift3, minio